# Invalid Floating Point Operation

Tags: delphi, point, floating, operation

I keep getting this error "Invalid Floating Point Operation".

I'm on Delphi 7.

```
uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
TlHelp32, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons, ComCtrls;

var //global
PHandle, cancel, bytes, scantype: integer;
```

...

```
procedure Tmain.scanbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    var max, address: Integer;
    floatinput, floatinput1, floatinput2, datafloat: Real;
    x: cardinal;
    itm: TListItem;
begin

  floatinput := StrToFloat(Trim(valueinput.Text));
  floatinput1 := StrToFloat(Trim(valueinput1.Text));
  floatinput2 := StrToFloat(Trim(valueinput2.Text));

  if floatinput2 < floatinput1 then
  begin
    floatinput1 := floatinput1 + floatinput2;
    floatinput2 := floatinput1 - floatinput2;
    floatinput1 := floatinput1 - floatinput2;
  end;

  result.Show;

  x := 0;
  address := 0;

  result.resultlist.Clear;

  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    statusbar1.Panels.Items[1].Text := 'Searching... ' + IntToStr(address * 100 div max) + '% (' + IntToStr(address div bytes) + ' out of ' + IntToStr(max div bytes) + ').';

    if ReadprocessMemory(PHandle, Ptr(address), @datafloat, bytes, x) then
      begin
        if (x > 0) then
        begin
          if scantype = 0 then
          begin
            if datafloat = floatinput then             //error here
            begin
              itm := result.resultlist.Items.Add;
              itm.Caption := '0x' + IntToHex(address,8);
              itm.SubItems.Add(FormatFloat('0.0#########', datafloat));
            end;
          end;
          if scantype = 1 then
          begin
            if datafloat > floatinput              //also here
            then begin
              itm := result.resultlist.Items.Add;
              itm.Caption := '0x' + IntToHex(address,8);
              itm.SubItems.Add(FormatFloat('0.0#########', datafloat));
            end;
          end;
          if scantype = 2 then
          begin
            if datafloat < floatinput     //here too
            then begin
              itm := result.resultlist.Items.Add;
              itm.Caption := '0x' + IntToHex(address,8);
              itm.SubItems.Add(FormatFloat('0.0#########', datafloat));
            end;
          end;
          if scantype = 2 then
          begin
            if (dataint <= intinput2) and (dataint >= intinput1)    //even here
            then begin
              itm := result.resultlist.Items.Add;
              itm.Caption := '0x' + IntToHex(address,8);
              itm.SubItems.Add(FormatFloat('0.0#########', datafloat));
            end;
          end;

        end;
      end;

    if x <> 0
    then address := address + x
    else address := address + bytes;

  until (address >= Max) or (cancel = 1);

end;
```

I even checked on the cpu window, and it happens because its trying to load a floating point value from a pointer that is pointing at a null value.

It's not the ReadMemory, because this little piece of code is on a while loop and it returns several valid values before running into this error.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What datatype is datafloat? You are comparing it to a variant (Null), but variant isn't a type that would be compatible with ReadProcessMemory. Do you mean to use Double?

Comment: The code you've posted will not compile, as the only valid use of `NULL` in Delphi is when using variants. Please post the full, **actual** code you're using. Asking us to debug code that isn't actually your code is a waste of both your time and ours. Post a compilable MCVE that demonstrates the problem if you want help here.

Comment: @GerryColl datafloat is real. Could you explain me what exactly happens when I try to compare a value with null then?

Comment: @KenWhite the full code is actually kinda big, and there's no need of filling up the topic with stuff that will probably be irrelevant to the problem. What information may I give you that will help you see more clearly?

Comment: Then trim it down to the minimal code required to demonstrate the problem first. We can't debug code we can't see, or code that can't compile. As I asked before, please post a MCVE that we can use.

Comment: @KenWhite - it will compile, but won't actually work as intended. Also D3X  has possibly (re)declared null as a constant, hiding the declaration in Variants (assuming D6+)

Comment: @D3X - `Null` is used for Variants, not simple datatypes. A `real` cannot be equal to null, or even `Nil` for that matter, it's not like the nullable types in .net

Comment: @GerryColl it was returning always true probably.. but i fixed it already.

Comment: @KenWhite Added more information to the topic..

Comment: @GerryColl: I have no idea what the OP declared (or didn't declare), as that information is not contained in the question. Speculation over what the OP might or might have done is meaningless; the code posted needs to represent a MCVE that we can compile in order to troubleshoot or debug. Without that, any conjecture over what might or might not be is simply noise and clutter.

Comment: Your edit improves things, but it's still not a MCVE. There's no indication of what the value of many variables contain, there are dependencies that aren't available (`result` and `Tmain`) and have no relevance to the issue, other UI code (the listview and edit stuff) that is also meaningless to the question. A console app with no UI content would be considerably better. Also, why would you just arbitrarily `ReadProcessMemory` on values entered into edit controls and then make the assumption that what you read is going to be a floating point value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two potential problems with the code that we can see.

First of all you do not check the return value of `ReadProcessMemory`. That call could fail for a variety of reasons. Since you don't check for errors you have no way of knowing whether or not the function call succeeded. Always check API calls for success. Read the docs on MSDN to find out how to do so. Usually this involves checking the function return value, as is the case here. If the function fails, then the floating point variable may contain uninitialized data and an error may ensue.

The other problem is that `datafloat` is being populated by reading bytes from another process. If those bytes do not represent a valid floating point value, then an exception will be raised if you try to operate on that value. Not all bit patterns represent valid floating point values. For instance, you may have hit upon a signaling NaN value. Perhaps you should be comparing with a `CompareMem` given that you appear to be reading arbitrary memory in what looks like an effort to reverse engineer some other program. Testing by bitwise comparison will avoid the risk of loading invalid values into floating registers.

Finally, I'm not sure what you mean by testing a floating point value against `null`, whatever `null` is. Floating point values are not nullable. It is very likely that you have a significant misunderstanding there.

Comment: Okay so i changed my code, and now i only proceed if the result of ReadProcessMemory is true, and then i check if the number of bytes read is > 0, and even though i don't fully understand why, the comparemem routine worked, but what if i want to know if datafloat > floatinput? Shouldn't I be able to compare two real values?

Comment: Actually.. nope. CompareMem is returning false even when it should return true, when i use normal comparison it returns only the values that it should, but always step in this error after a while..

Comment: Okay, i fixed it, your answer was actually really usefull. What i did was declare 'Math' in uses and then check if 'datafloat' is not a NaN by using the IsNan routine, thank you.

Comment: CompareMem will work if you use it right. If you want to do other than equality comparison for non-zero, finite values it will work. Using IsNaN is a good option. The whole point is that you are operating on values whose provenance you don't know.